# Use of the word родня

Tags: выбор-слова, лексикон

When would a person use the word родня? I know its literal meaning is relative but what does it loosely translate to in English in its contextual meaning?

Comment: Is not it an analogue of English word *kin*? Though for me, kin is rather outdated and pompous, while родня has low speech register (не могу перевести слово просторечный).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Word *родня* does not just mean *a relative* - it refers to an extended group of relatives, essentially all and any people even remotely related to the person in question.  A rather close English translation is *extended family*, however Russian *родня* has more of a connotation of familiarity.  Quite often, it's used to describe the collection of *all relatives*, e.g. *вся родня*. For example:

> Если вся моя родня будет ей не рада,
>   Не пеняйте на меня - я уйду из стада.

Another related word is *родичи*, which is colloquial form of *родственники*, meaning *relatives*.

**EDIT:** Following a comment from Andrey 'lolmaus' Mikhaylov, it's worth adding that word *родня* may also be used to indicate *some (unqualified) relatives* (e.g. "Провел выходные с родней") - yet it pretty much always used to refer to a plural *relatives* rather than one individual relative.

Comment: Though i agree with this answer, i would like to emphasize that *родня* can be used as a direct synonym for *relatives*. "Я провел выходные с родней" = "I spent the weekend with my relatives". This doesn't necessarily mean that there was a clan gathering of two hundred people, it could mean just four people as well.

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov Agree; my reference to _"all and any"_, I believe, addresses it. _Выходные с родней_ would certainly qualify as _weekend with [some/any] relatives_.  I'll update the answer to add _some_ as an option.

Comment: I would like to add that "родичи" can sometimes be used by young people to informally refer to their parents, mostly because "родители" sounds a bit too formal and is long to pronounce. E.g. "Родичи на дачу уехали, а брат остался дома." However, "Родня уехала на дачу." implies that the brother went with them.

Comment: Can it be usd by couples to address each other affectionately meaning darling or sweetheart, etc?

Comment: @Divi I can't imagine this word being used in such context.  First, it always refers to relatives (blood relatives), second, it's not affectionate at all - quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say about your relatives/family/dear friends as "they are my Родные/ they are Родные to me". When not used in plural, You can say it as You'd say sweetheart/dear/dearest - "родная" (f) and "родной" (m). For example, 'my sweetheart/my dear' to a woman - "родная my/my родная".

Although, google would translate "native", as in native land/home land - "родная land". But we all know, google translator usually sucks when it comes to context.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Basically the question was about роднЯ, not about роднАя.

Comment: Thanks I think that answers my question a lot better and as I am new to Russian, this difference of words makes more sense

Comment: Artemix, yes, I actually wanted to add my suggestion as a comment (and not a separate answer), but it didn't allow due to lack of reputation, so I had to put it as an actual answer. Bottom line, it helped! ;)

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, it is about a different word.